# Calculating distance features within a shapefile - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, routing

I have a file that has a list of postal codes of customers and the main store they frequently visit (e.g., Customer 1, Customer 2, and Customer 3, visit Circle Centre). In ArcGIS I want to be able to calculate the distance between customers and their frequently visited stores. Has anyone ever done this and know what tool to use?

I know there is a tool that assigns points to the nearest feature, however, that's not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: do you need Street distance from a Customer to a store location?

Comment: Yes, in I need distance in km. This is something I run on diff results all the time. People tell us where they visit and we have to identify how far they travel to those locations in kilometres.

Comment: Can you describe the file that you have? is it a point shapefile of customers and another point shapefile of stores? Having trouble visualizing your question.

Comment: It’s pretty much a survey file (excel sheet) with each customers address and their favourite grocer that they frequently visit on weekends.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to tell the travel distance between each customer and their store, you would need a road network. I assume you do not have any available (such as Street Map Premium product or own compilation of HERE/TomTom data) routable road network to use. Moreover, in order to build and route using local road network dataset, you would need an extension Network Analyst which you might not have purchased.

Since you are an ArcGIS user, you should be eligible to use of [ArcGIS Online Route Service](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1feb41652c5c4bd2ba5c60df2b4ea2c4) which provides access to the various routing services you could use. This is by far the most efficient way for you to get started as you do not need to build this road network on your own.

Talk to your local Esri tech support to get started. Using this service in ArcMap would let you create multiple routes (from `Customer 1` to `Circle Centre`, from `Customer 2` to `Circle Centre` and so forth). After solving the routes, you can export the travel time and distance for each route into an external Excel sheet using the [Table To Excel](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-excel.htm) geoprocessing tool.

However,

> Please be aware that each route you calculate with the ArcGIS Online
>   World Route Service causes ArcGIS Online service credits to be
>   consumed.

Service credits is something you can buy should you have many routes (you pay per route). However, it might be cheaper to use the [OD Matrix service](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=097e4845a63f4bfe89445cb58ed99a17) - in this case you would load all your customers into origins and all your shops into the destinations. Then you would get all possible permutations (each customer routed to each destination). This operation is cheaper because you are not generating any visualisation of the route and directions (route guidance) when solving the OD matrix.